# How to prevent the onmouseleave event from being triggered outside the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a little try below. When i enter the mouse inside of the basket, a dropdown with a button appears. When we click the button a modal appears.I want the modal to close only when the close modal button is clicked. But when we take the mouse out of the browser the `hideDropdown` function is triggered and the modal closes. I sent the `hideDropdown` function as a prop to the component whose Modal state was updated, but this time only the `hideDropdown` function worked and the `isModalShow` state was not updated. How can i solve this?

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-buck-1lgmiu

Answer (score 1):

This was tricky but i finally got it. You have to add the functions like below.
The side effect is the open modal button will toggle sometime but that can be changed if you lift up the modal as it depends on the dropdown, I guess or implement simply using CSS instead which would be much easier.

But coming to your main question for `onMouseleave` you can do like following. This is basically checking the boundaries of the browser. Added 10 instead of 0 because the scrollbar was somehow messing with the event firing in codepen. So, added as a safeguard.

Also, used `onMouseOver` instead of `onMouseEnter`.

```
 const hideDropdown = (event) => {
    if (
      event.clientY <= 10 ||
      event.clientX <= 10 ||
      event.clientX >= window.innerWidth - 10 ||
      event.clientY >= window.innerHeight - 10
    ) {
      console.log("I'm out");
      return;
    } 
    setIsDropdownShow(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" onMouseOver={showDropdown} onMouseLeave={hideDropdown}>
      <span className="basket">Basket</span>
      {isDropdownShow && <Dropdown hideDropdown={hideDropdown} />}
    </div>
```

Here is the sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-antonelli-fwnoi1?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to unlink the Modal from the isDropdownShow property so that it can be toggled only the button OpenModal and CloseModal... Just a workaround

```
import "./styles.css";
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isDropdownShow, setIsDropdownShow] = useState(false);
  const [isModalShow, setIsModalShow] = useState(false);
  
  const showDropdown = () => {
    setIsDropdownShow(true);
  };

const showModal = () => {
    setIsModalShow(true);
  };
const hideModal = () => {
    setIsModalShow(false);
  };

  const hideDropdown = () => {
    setIsDropdownShow(false);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      
    >
  <div
      onMouseEnter={showDropdown}
      onMouseLeave={hideDropdown}>
      <span 
      
      className="basket">Basket</span>
      {isDropdownShow && <button onClick={()=>showModal}> Open 
     Modal<button/>}
  </div>
      <Dropdown hideModal={hideModal} IsModalShow={IsModalShow} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In here you are targeting only `span` element for mouse events. The dropdown will be visible only when the mouse enters the basket. When you try to click the button the dropdown will disappear because you exited the basket element and we will not be able to click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Basic solution would be checking if user in window or not with `window`. Here is the working codesandbox sample https://codesandbox.io/embed/heuristic-pasteur-u4cd5e?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import "./styles.css";
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isDropdownShow, setIsDropdownShow] = useState(false);

  const showDropdown = () => {
    setIsDropdownShow(true);
  };

  const hideDropdown = (event) => {
    if( typeof window !== "undefined" &&
         window.document &&
         window.document.createElement ){
      return;
    }
    setIsDropdownShow(false);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      onMouseEnter={showDropdown}
      onMouseLeave={hideDropdown}
    >
      <span className="basket">Basket</span>
      {isDropdownShow && <Dropdown hideDropdown={hideDropdown} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```